# Writing to Heroku logs in Django

Tags: python, django, logging, heroku

I've created a project in Django and have deployed it to Heroku. Unfortunately, a number of things that were working locally, now don't work on Heroku. To troubleshoot I need to be able to write to the Heroku logs when my program runs so that I can troubleshoot better. So far I have not gotten it to work

My `settings/staging.py` file contains:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
        },
    },
}
```

I have an app called accounts, so my `accounts/views.py` file contains:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def auth_profile(request):
    log.debug('TESTING THE DEBUGGER')
```

When `auth_profile` is accessed I want to see the text `'TESTING THE DEBUGGER'` show up in the Heroku logs, but so far I get nothing.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Logging to the console should do what you want. How do you load `settings/staging.py`?

Comment: I think I just solved it myself
changed settings/staging.py to include
   ` 'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
        },
        'accounts': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
        },
    },`

Answer (score 0):

I think if you drop a `log.error` you would probably see something.

I had the same problem and it turns out heroku's settings tool breaks the pre-existing `LOGGING` setup. The logger you are using is not registered with django but is making its own way to the console using python's standard logging system.

Try doing:

```py
django_heroku.settings(locals(), logging=False)
```

Or better yet, don't use it at all anymore since this package is no longer maintained anyway.